# Social Login from angular to backend (laminas api tool)

Tags: angular, google-signin, laminas-api-tools

Can anyone point me out in the right direction?

I am trying to integrate google login to my angular project. My backend is in the [laminas API tool framework](https://api-tools.getlaminas.org/).

This angular module looks good to achieve that. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login

As mentioned in that angular module, `You can communicate the auth_token to your server to authenticate the user in server and make API calls from server.`

I am trying to find the best approach to achieve this. **How do I use `auth_token` in my backend?**

Should I re-call to google with that `auth_token` from the backend to check if the user has been authorized? For me this doesn't look right, since to login a user I will have to make 2 API calls (from angular and backend) to google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up recalling google to verify the `auth_token` from API too. Anyone knows a better answer please add here, will accept.